# How to account for resizing of images in image shears

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to create a program where the user enters an image and a transformation matrix and sees it applied to the image. All of the 2x2 matrix transformations I have tested so far work except for shears. This is because the image size is actually changed in the case of a shear (compared to a reflection/rotation etc.).

I believe I either need to resize the image itself after applying the transformation or the window, but I am unable to figure out how to do so. I tried utilizing the resize() and windowResize() functions, but was not able to accomplish what I wanted. How can I resize the image itself or the window (if needed) after applying a transformation matrix such as a shear to include the entirety of the output image in the window? My code so far is shown below:

```
int main()
{
// Query user for file input
std::cout << "Please enter an image file: ";
std::string fileName;
std::cin >> fileName;
std::ifstream inputFile(fileName);
// Check if file exists
if (!inputFile)
{
    std::cout << "Error opening file";
    return 1;
}

// Query user for 2x2 transformation matrix input
std::cout << "Enter the four values of your 2x2 transformation matrix"
          << " separated by spaces: ";
double a, b, c, d;
std::cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;

// Read in and display input image
Mat src = imread(fileName);
imshow("Input Image", src);

// Matrix to translate the image to OpenCV's origin
Mat originMat = (Mat_<double>(3, 3)
<< 1, 0, -(src.cols / 2), 0, 1, -(src.rows / 2), 0, 0, 1);

// Matrix to apply the given transformation matrix
Mat tMat = (Mat_<double>(3, 3) //
<< a, b, 0, c, d, 0, 0, 0, 1);

// Matrix to translate the image back to its original position
Mat tOriginal = (Mat_<double>(3, 3)
<< 1, 0, (src.cols / 2), 0, 1, (src.rows / 2), 0, 0, 1);

// Multiply matrices to make things simpler
// and preserve all aspects of the image
Mat compMat = tOriginal * (tMat * originMat);
// Apply the given transformation matrix to the image

warpPerspective(src, src, compMat, src.size(),
INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar());

// Display the final output image and wait for input before closing window
Size size = Size(900, 900);
imshow("Output Image", src);

// This doesn't really work. It resizes the image to scale as well
// which defeats the whole purpose and resizing the image itself
// leaves some parts of it cut off
resizeWindow("Output Image", size);
waitKey();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: the image corners have coordinates. top left is (0,0) and you can guess the others. send those through the matrix to get the resulting coordinates. then take the bounding box of those. once you know the translation you require, you can multiply that onto your transformation matrix (affine or homography) using matrix mult. -- consider an affine transformation, which can represent translation. you'll need a 2x3 matrix. -- use `warpAffine` for pictures and `transform` for points. if you use a full 3x3 *homography*, you'll need `warpPerspective` for images and `perspectiveTransform` for points

Comment: let me know if you have further questions. if that actually answered your question, let me know that too and I'll post it as an answer -- I'd recommend using python. C++ is awful for prototyping/understanding.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I'm a little confused, so are you saying to multiply the transformation matrix by the coordinates of the bounding box of the original image just to see what the new coordinates would be and therefore find the translation I need? And then multiply that matrix by the compMat I already created?

Comment: yes. to find the translation you need, and also the new size that can contain the entire sheared picture.